# Unable To Connect mdb VIEW Table via pyodbc Python

Tags: python, ms-access, view, pyodbc

I am now facing a difficulty connecting VIEW table in mdb file using pyodbc.

Current code is as follows:
(Previous Provider: Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0)

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.pooling = False

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:***.mdb;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

for table_info in crsr.tables(tableType='TABLE'):
    print(table_info.table_name)

strSQL = "SELECT A,B FROM tableC WHERE ** ORDER BY B"

crsr.execute(strSQL)

for row in crsr.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

When it works, `for table_info in crsr.tables(tableType='TABLE'):` seems to have no issue.
This is because   `print(table_info.table_name)` displays several table names.

However, when `crsr.execute(strSQL)` is done, exeption error has raised and following message
**('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] ODBC--connection to 'VIEW' failed. (-2001) (SQLExecDirectW)")**
is shown.

It would be appreciated to instruct me how to overcome this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: When you open the database in the Access UI and double-click `tableC` are you prompted for a username and password?

Comment: Yes. However, though```r'UID=**;' r'PWD=**'``` are added to ```conn_str ```, same error occurs.

Comment: Adding UID and PWD to the connection string in Python will pass the credentials to the Access driver but they won't get passed through to the server hosting the ODBC linked table. You either need to re-link the tables with the [Save password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y48wL.png) option, or use something like Windows Authentication for SQL Server when creating the linked table.